# Faster way to count the distinct values within multiple arrays from mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, java-stream, query-optimization, spring-webflux

I have mongodb document in this format :

```json
{
    //-- type and date
    "date": "2023-11-09",
    "type": "my_type",
    "resources": "1111,5555,2222,3333,1111", 
}
```

i'm trying to get all document of a specific day, (up to 500.000 documents) and count the distinct values within the resources.
for that this aggregation will do the job :

```json
[
  {
    $match: {
      date: "2024-01-01"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      resources: "$resources"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$resources"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      dv: {
        $addToSet: "$resources"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $size: "$dv"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**The problem** is that this is a very slow query and it takes more than 15 seconds,
I'im lookin for other approach to get the job done in timely manner; knowing that i'm in reactive spring boot application.

Comment: Is that query used often enough to warrant pre-calculating the distinct resources array, and storing that in the document?

Comment: I have other fields that I want to filter with each time, to calculate all the possible values is impossible, so to answer you question there is no way to pre-calculate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  date: "2023-11-09"
  }
},
{
"$project": {
  split_field: {
    $split: [
      "$resources",
      ","
    ]
    }
  }
 },
 {
"$group": {
  _id: "",
  tot: {
    "$addToSet": "$split_field"
    }
  }
},
{
 "$project": {
  total: {
    $size: {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$tot",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$setUnion": [
            "$$this",
            "$$value"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
])
```

Explanation:

1. $match the documents with necessary date
2. $project to split the $resources elements and convert to array
3. $group to have single document with the arrays ( removing duplicated array )
4. $project/$reduce the $size of $setUnion(to remove duplicated array elements )

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PKckPelzeND)

In the Playground2 example $project/$group stages joined in 1x stage which is expected to be even faster:

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b2aIBl4JALI)

Important: Don't forget to add index on your "date" field if you dont have yet one.

Comment: But here we don't have duplicated arrays, we have just duplicated values over arrays, so an unwind operator must take place in order to get document with just on resource and then group -> addToset to remove duplicates !

Comment: I've tried your aggregation, I get this error: BSONObj size: 33856519 (0x2049C07) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: null 

in the stage : 
"$group": {
  _id: "",
  tot: {
    "$addToSet": "$split_field"
    }
  }
},

Comment: On your 1st comment: "resources": "1111,5555,2222,3333,1111" from what I see is a string , why do you need to do "$unwind" to a string value?  , On your 2nd comment: Indeed it looks you have huge amount of documents so you hit some default threshold limits , are we talking about duplicated strings or duplicated values in arrays , please , clarify ?

Comment: I want to $unwind because after the $group stage I'll end by a document having all the string values in one array, to count the distinct within this array i unwind to be able to use add to set.  Otherwise how can I bypass the problem of the threshold passed ? so i can test your aggregation performance

Comment: maybe good to edit your example document so it is seen as an array then , so your array will look something like this after the group stage: [ "1111,5555,2222,3333,1111" , "1111,5555,2222,3333,1111" ]  then?

Comment: The group stage is used just for me to be able to use $addToSet, for me there no duplicate resources string the resource is "1111" for example ; and then i want to count distinct ones ; which are "1111", "2222", "3333"... if i have for example  the resource "1111" 3 times but in different documents; i will count just one

Comment: okey , so my answer is correct then , but documents are too many for such an approach with single group stage and maybe best to think about splitting/grouping  in portions ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256836/discussion-between-moussa-elaq-and-r2d2).

Comment: how can I do that ! knowing that it works fine with $unwind but I want better performance